# Select two elements from an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

Suppose there is an array like this one:

```
list = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e"]
```

We want to create a cycle where every next element is different from the previous element and the first element is different from the last element.

```
required = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "c", "e", "d", "e"]
```

How is this done in ruby?

```
def create_cycle
  temp = Array.new($input)
  i, j, counter = 0
  while i == 0
    while (counter != $input.length)
      j = rand(1..$input.length-1).floor
      unless !($input[i][0].to_s.eql?$input[j][0])
        $solution.push($input[i])
        $solution.push($input[j])
        puts input[i], input[j]
        $input.delete_at(i)
        $input.delete_at(j)
        counter = counter + 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to learn this. Thank you for your help.

Additional notes:

1. The elements a, b, c, d, e represent special format strings, where
   a certain property is common among them, thus the first element "a" 
   shares a property with the next element "a" but is not equivalent to
   the first.
2. In the case it isn't possible to create a cycle, then, it is enough to raise a flag in command line.

Comment: What if it is not possible? Say, [a,a,a,b]?

Comment: Thank you pointing this out, @Anand. We need only let the user know in the case a cycle is not possible. Cary, thank you for your suggestion. I will include that right away.

Answer (score 1):

I might do it like this:

```
>> list = [a, a, a, b, b, c, d, e, e]
>> list.sort.each_slice((list.size/2.0).round).reduce(:zip).flatten.compact
=> [a, c, a, d, a, e, b, e, b]
```

The general method is to:

1. sort the list, so all identical members are adjacent
2. divide the list in half from the middle
3. interleave the two halves together

Comment: How do you know the elements are sortable?

Comment: How do you know `size` is defined for `a`, and what does that do?

Comment: s/`a`/`list`/ and if `sort` isn't defined `group_by`+`flatten` are a suitable alternative

Comment: Thank you for your help @user12341234. I like what you've done with the groupings. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not care about the order being the same as in the original array, and it is ok to have duplicates if there is no way, and also assuming the list is presorted, here is one approach - it just keeps adding elements from the beginning and end of the list till there are no elements left:

```
def interleaver list
  result = []
  el = list.first
  while(el)
    el = list.shift
    if el
      result << el
    else
      return result
    end
    el = list.pop
    if el
      result << el
    else
      return result
    end
  end 
  result
end

> a = 'a'
> b = 'b'
> c = 'c'
> d = 'd'
> e = 'e'
> list = [a, a, a, b, b, c, d, e, e]
> interleaver(list)
=> ["a", "e", "a", "e", "a", "d", "b", "c", "b"]
```

But if such interleaving is not possible, you will get duplicates:

```
> list = [a, a, a, b]
> interleaver(list)
#=> ["a","b","a","a"]
```

Comment: Ah! Nice, very clever. Thanks, this will definitely work as long as there is a final check. Thank you for your help, @Anand.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain such a string, or demonstrate that no such string exists, with the following recursive method.

**Code**

```
def doit(remaining, partial=[])
  first_partial, last_partial = partial.first, partial.last
  if remaining.size == 1
    return ([first_partial, last_partial] & remaining).empty? ?
      partial + remaining : nil
  end
  remaining.uniq.each_with_index do |s,i|
    next if s == last_partial
    rem = remaining.dup
    rem.delete_at(i)
    rv = doit(rem, partial + [s])
    return rv if rv
  end
  nil
end
```

**Examples**

```
list = %w| a a b |
  #=> ["a", "a", "b"]
doit list
  #=> nil
```

The above demonstrates that the three elements of `list` cannot be permuted to satisfy the two ordering requirements.

```
list = %w| a a a b b c d e e |
  #=> ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e"] 
doit list    
  #=> ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "b", "e", "d", "e"]
```

This took 0.0042 second to solve on a newish MacBook Pro.

```
list = %w| a a a a a a a b b c d e e f f f g g g g h i i i i j j |
  #=> ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e",
  #    "f", "f", "f", "g", "g", "g", "g", "h", "i", "i", "i", "i", "j", "j"] 
doit list    
  #=> ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d", "e", "f",
  #    "e", "f", "g", "f", "g", "h", "g", "h", "i", "j", "i", "j", "i", "j"]
```

This took 0.0059 seconds to solve.

Out of curiosity, I then tried

```
list = (%w| a a a a a a a b b c d e e f f f g g g g h i i i i j j |).shuffle
  #=> ["a", "c", "f", "b", "d", "i", "a", "a", "i", "a", "a", "g", "g",
  #    "a", "g", "i", "j", "b", "h", "j", "e", "e", "a", "g", "f", "i", "f"] 
doit list    
  #=> ["a", "c", "f", "b", "d", "i", "a", "i", "a", "g", "a", "g", "a",
  #    "g", "i", "g", "j", "b", "h", "j", "e", "a", "e", "g", "f", "i", "f"]
```

This took a whooping 1.16 seconds to solve, suggesting that it may be desirable to pre-sort `list` (`doit(list.sort)`) if, of course, `list` is sortable.

Comment: Thank you @Cary! Your knowledge of ruby syntax overwhelms me. It took me quite some time to recognize what you were doing. Thanks for the help.